# sorting out four integers: VBA Excel

Tags: vba, sorting, integer

I have four integers stored in the variables. What would be the way to find the biggest, second biggest, third, and the smallest? Is there an elegant way of doing it without writing a long code?

Comment: You can use SMALL and LARGE functions from Excel.

Comment: would you mind interpreting this as the code example?

Comment: Apologies, i understood the question as being worksheet range based, not 4 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant and common ways to sort integers are the [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Bubblesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithms.

But if you have only four integers, this may be a little overkill. So you could also implement a simple `if-else` algorithm.

**Quicksort**

```
Private Sub QuickSort( _ 
                      ByRef ArrayToSort As Variant, _ 
                      ByVal Low As Long, _ 
                      ByVal High As Long) 
Dim vPartition As Variant, vTemp As Variant 
Dim i As Long, j As Long 
  If Low > High Then Exit Sub  
  vPartition = ArrayToSort((Low + High) \ 2) 
  i = Low: j = High 
  Do 
    Do While ArrayToSort(i) < vPartition 
      i = i + 1 
    Loop 
    Do While ArrayToSort(j) > vPartition 
      j = j - 1 
    Loop 
    If i <= j Then 
      vTemp = ArrayToSort(j) 
      ArrayToSort(j) = ArrayToSort(i) 
      ArrayToSort(i) = vTemp 
      i = i + 1 
      j = j - 1 
    End If 
  Loop Until i > j 
  If (j - Low) < (High - i) Then 
    QuickSort ArrayToSort, Low, j 
    QuickSort ArrayToSort, i, High 
  Elsea 
    QuickSort ArrayToSort, i, High 
    QuickSort ArrayToSort, Low, j 
  End If 
End Sub
```

**Bubblesort**

```
For j = UBound(ArrayToSort) - 1 To LBound(ArrayToSort) Step -1 

    For i = LBound(ArrayToSort) To j 
      If ArrayToSort(i) > ArrayToSort(i + 1) Then  
        vTemp = ArrayToSort(i) 
        ArrayToSort(i) = ArrayToSort(i + 1) 
        ArrayToSort(i + 1) = vTemp 
      End If 
    Next i 
  Next j
```

[Code from german MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979305.aspx)

Comment: thanks! doesn't seem easy to understand, though,but will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

4 elements can be sorted using 5 if / swap statements (sorting network):

```
    if (a[0] > a[2]) { swap(a[0], a[2]); }
    if (a[1] > a[3]) { swap(a[1], a[3]); }
    if (a[0] > a[1]) { swap(a[0], a[1]); }
    if (a[2] > a[3]) { swap(a[2], a[3]); }
    if (a[1] > a[2]) { swap(a[1], a[2]); }
```

Comment: thanks. I wonder what's the language the code is written in? And could the "swap" method be used in VBA for Excel, or there's an alternative?

Comment: It's pseudo-code or C++ with namespace std for the swap function. To swap a and b, using a temp variable called t, use | t = a | a = b | b = t | . Here is an [example VBA swap](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/swap-values.html) .